# Delayed expansion does not work in entire batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am working on a script that will use Putty command line to login to several systems just by executing a batch file. The batch reads the list of server names I wish to launch from a text file without issue.

The issue arises when using the password entered at a "`set /p`". The password has special characters in it, such as the ampersand. To use the variable, I am attempting to use `DELAYEDEXPANSION`.

I can echo the variable with the password fine using `!pass!` However, when used within a for loop where putty is called, the `DELAYEDEXPANSION` seems to fail. The result is literally !pass!.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /p  destination="Enter the file name: "
set /p "pass=Your LAN PASSword: "

ECHO Pass=!pass!

pause
for /F %%z in (%destination%) do (
start C:\DEV\Utilities\putty\putty -ssh %username%@%%z -pw !pass! -m "C:\DEV\Utilities\putty\commands" -t
timeout /t 01 /nobreak > NUL
) 
pause
```

If I use the variable with percent signs like `%pass%`, the password is not correct. For instance `"c&ndyCone"` ends up as `"c  & ndyCone"` (less the quotes).

Any suggestions to pass the correct password to Putty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem here isn't about delayed expansion but the neither double quoted nor escaped char `&`.
So it is interpreted as command concatenation thus breaking your one command line into two - the second starting with the remainder of the password which is hardly a valid command: `ndyCone`

Second is that start interprets the first argument in double quotes as the window title.

Try:

```
::commented out SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /p  destination="Enter the file name: "
set /p "pass=Your LAN PASSword: "

ECHO Pass="%pass%"

pause
for /F %%z in (%destination%) do (
start "" C:\DEV\Utilities\putty\putty -ssh %username%@%%z -pw "%pass%" -m "C:\DEV\Utilities\putty\commands" -t
timeout /t 01 /nobreak > NUL
) 
pause
```

Comment: I like this and it appears to work. To build on my question, will this work if there are quotes as part of the password? Single or double, open or closed? Sorry if that sounds confusing.

Comment: A double quote may be escaped with a backslash inside the enclosing double quotes. Single quotes have no special meaning in batch.